# JQuery/JavaScript - Perform calculations on 2 cells in each row and return results to 3rd cell in each row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to do some calculations on two cells in each row (each has a unique class) and return the results to a third cell (has its own class as well). I have put each class into its own array and I am able to access the elements within. I am not entirely sure I am evening approaching this the right way, any help would be much appreciated. The math is **(sub1 - sub2) / sub2**

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/tfopbk9h/6/) and here is my html for my table:

```js
var sub1 = [];
var sub2 = [];
var sub3 = [];
$(function subP() {
  $('.sub1').each(function(i, e) {
    sub1.push($(e).text());
  });
  $('.sub2').each(function(i, e) {
    sub2.push($(e).text());
  });
  $('.sub3').each(function(i, e) {
    sub3.push($(e).text());
  });
  var x = (sub1[0] - sub2[0]) / sub2[0];
  $('.sub3:first').html(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <th>test0</th>
    <th>test1</th>
    <th>test2</th>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub1">1</td>
      <td class="sub2">2</td>
      <td class="sub3">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub1">3</td>
      <td class="sub2">4</td>
      <td class="sub3">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub1">5</td>
      <td class="sub2">6</td>
      <td class="sub3">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd recommend including your JS code in your question, as well (i.e., not just a link to JSFiddle).

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Lekbmxd3/

Comment: that did it! thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't loaded the jQuery library in your fiddle. That's why your code doesn't work, otherwise your code does something. It gets the result of calculation and sets it to *all* `.sub3` elements.

This is one way of getting the expected result.

```
$('.sub3').text(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var sub1 = +$this.siblings('.sub1').text();
   var sub2 = +$this.siblings('.sub2').text();
   return ((sub1 - sub2) / sub2).toFixed(2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it

```js
var sub1 = [];
var sub2 = [];
var sub3 = [];
$(function subP() {
  $('.sub1').each(function(i, e) {
    sub1.push($(e).text());
  });
  $('.sub2').each(function(i, e) {
    sub2.push($(e).text());
  });
  $('.sub3').each(function(i, e) {
    var x = (sub1[i] - sub2[i]) / sub2[i];
    $(this).html(x);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <th>test0</th>
    <th>test1</th>
    <th>test2</th>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub1">1</td>
      <td class="sub2">2</td>
      <td class="sub3">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub1">3</td>
      <td class="sub2">4</td>
      <td class="sub3">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub1">5</td>
      <td class="sub2">6</td>
      <td class="sub3">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```